# Having trouble installing hyde with pip in a virtualenv in Windows

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv, pip, hyde

So this is what I get when I try to `pip install hyde` in a virtualenv in Windows. How come this is happening and how do I solve it?

```
C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\Art_website>Scripts\activate
(Art_website) C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\3ambi_website>pip install hyde
Downloading/unpacking hyde
  Downloading hyde-0.8.4.tar.gz (1.3Mb): 1.3Mb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package hyde

Downloading/unpacking argparse (from hyde)
  Downloading argparse-1.2.1.tar.gz (69Kb): 69Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package argparse

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.orig' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.rej' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\_build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env24'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env25'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env26'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env27'
Downloading/unpacking commando (from hyde)
  Downloading commando-0.1.2a.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package commando

Downloading/unpacking jinja2 (from hyde)
  Downloading Jinja2-2.6.tar.gz (389Kb): 389Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package jinja2

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs\_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'jinja2'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'jinja2'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
Downloading/unpacking pyYAML (from hyde)
  Downloading PyYAML-3.10.tar.gz (241Kb): 241Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pyYAML

Downloading/unpacking markdown (from hyde)
  Downloading Markdown-2.1.1.zip (341Kb): 341Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package markdown

Downloading/unpacking smartypants (from hyde)
  Downloading smartypants-1.6.0.3.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package smartypants

Downloading/unpacking pygments (from hyde)
  Downloading Pygments-1.5.tar.gz (3.7Mb): 3.7Mb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pygments

Downloading/unpacking typogrify-hyde (from hyde)
  Downloading hyde-setup
  Running setup.py egg_info for package typogrify-hyde

    warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'docs'
Installing collected packages: hyde, argparse, commando, jinja2, pyYAML, markdown, smartypants, pygments, typogr
  Running setup.py install for hyde

    Installing hyde-script.py script to C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\Art_website\Scripts
    Installing hyde.exe script to C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\Art_website\Scripts
  Running setup.py install for argparse

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.orig' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.rej' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\_build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env24'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env25'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env26'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env27'
  Running setup.py install for commando

  Running setup.py install for jinja2

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs\_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'jinja2'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'jinja2'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
  Running setup.py install for pyYAML
    checking if libyaml is compilable
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\Art_website\build\pyYAML\setup.py", line 344, in <module>
        'test': test,
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\Art_website\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg\setu
n run
        return _install.run(self)
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\Art_website\build\pyYAML\setup.py", line 171, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\Art_website\build\pyYAML\setup.py", line 213, in build_extensi
        with_ext = self.check_extension_availability(ext)
      File "C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\Art_website\build\pyYAML\setup.py", line 239, in check_extensi
        depends=ext.depends)
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 469, in compile
        self.initialize()
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 379, in initialize
        vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 295, in query_vcvarsall
        raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
    ValueError: [u'path']
    Complete output from command "C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\Art_website\Scripts\python.exe" -c "impo
ious\\Desktop\\My Dropbox\\Art_website\\build\\pyYAML\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\
ll --single-version-externally-managed --record c:\users\s3z\appdata\local\temp\pip-yffhnx-record\install-re
aeious\Desktop\My Dropbox\Art_website\include\site\python2.7":
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\yaml

copying lib\yaml\composer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\yaml

copying lib\yaml\constructor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\yaml

copying lib\yaml\cyaml.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\yaml

copying lib\yaml\dumper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\yaml

copying lib\yaml\emitter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\yaml

copying lib\yaml\error.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\yaml

copying lib\yaml\events.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\yaml

copying lib\yaml\loader.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\yaml

copying lib\yaml\nodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\yaml

copying lib\yaml\parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\yaml

copying lib\yaml\reader.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\yaml

copying lib\yaml\representer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\yaml

copying lib\yaml\resolver.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\yaml

copying lib\yaml\scanner.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\yaml

copying lib\yaml\serializer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\yaml

copying lib\yaml\tokens.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\yaml

copying lib\yaml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\yaml

running build_ext

creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7

creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release

checking if libyaml is compilable

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\Art_website\build\pyYAML\setup.py", line 344, in <module>

    'test': test,

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\Art_website\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg\setuptoo
n

    return _install.run(self)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run

    self.run_command('build')

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run

    self.run_command(cmd_name)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\Art_website\build\pyYAML\setup.py", line 171, in run

    _build_ext.run(self)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run

    self.build_extensions()

  File "C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\Art_website\build\pyYAML\setup.py", line 213, in build_extensions

    with_ext = self.check_extension_availability(ext)

  File "C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\Art_website\build\pyYAML\setup.py", line 239, in check_extension_a

    depends=ext.depends)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 469, in compile

    self.initialize()

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 379, in initialize

    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 295, in query_vcvarsall

    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))

ValueError: [u'path']

----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\Art_website\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import setuptools;__file__='C
\\Art_website\\build\\pyYAML\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'e
nally-managed --record c:\users\s3z\appdata\local\temp\pip-yffhnx-record\install-record.txt --install-header
\Art_website\include\site\python2.7" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\3ambi_web
Storing complete log in C:\Users\s3z\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.log

(Art_website) C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\3ambi_website>
```